# Extracting Actionscript from .fla file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm just starting to learn some actionscript and have been given an example project that I'd like to hack around on a bit. I'm learning AS by writing in a text editor and compiling with mxmlc. I have Flash CS3, but I'd like to learn with the editor.

The project that I've been given was delivered only in a .fla project. How can I extract the raw actionscript from the .fla?

The example is here: http://krazydad.com/bestiary/bestiary_piechart.html

Answer (score 5):

1. Open up the Movie Explorer (alt+F3 on PC).
2. Hit the far-right menu button ("customize what to show").
3. In the upper part of the dialog, turn off everything except "ActionScript". In the lower part, turn on both options. Hit OK.
4. All frame scripts in the FLA will now show up in the explorer. You can browse them, and double-click each to jump to where they are defined. You can also right-click in the explorer and select "Copy all text to clipboard" to get everything in one go. (But it won't necessarily be in meaningful order.)
5. ???
6. Profit!

Answer (score -3):

ctrl+c

I'm sure that's not the answer your looking for, but that's what it's going to take. Lucky by the look of things there isn't a lot of code.

Comment: I suspect it would be helpful to expand on that... "ctrl+c" isn't helpful by itself... where? which tools?